# AWS Elasticache backed by memcached CPU usage flat line at 1%

Tags: amazon-web-services, memcached, amazon-elasticache, spymemcached

I've created an ElastiCache cluster in AWS, with node type as t3.micro (500 MB, 2 vCPUs and network up to 5 gigabit). My current setup is having 3 nodes for High Availability, each node is in a different AZ.

I'm using the AWS labs memcached client for Java (https://github.com/awslabs/aws-elasticache-cluster-client-memcached-for-java) that allows auto discovery of nodes, i.e. I only need to provide the cluster DNS record and the client will automatically discover all nodes within that cluster.

I intermittently get some timeout errors:

```
1) Error in custom provider, net.spy.memcached.OperationTimeoutException: Timeout waiting for value: waited 2,500 ms. Node status: Connection Status { /XXX.XX.XX.XXX:11211 active: false, authed: true, last read: 44,772 ms ago /XXX.XX.XX.XXX:11211 active: true, authed: true, last read: 4 ms ago /XXX.XX.XX.XXX:11211 active: true, authed: true, last read: 6 ms ago
```

I'm trying to understand what's the problem, but nothing really stands out by looking at the CloudWatch metrics.

The only thing that looks a bit weird is the CPU utilization graph:
[image: CPU utilization graph]

The CPU always maxes out at 1% during peak hours, so I'm trying to understand how to read this value and whether this is not a 1% but more of a 100%, indicating that there's a bottleneck on the CPU.

Any help on this?

Comment: Did you solve this in the end? We also have CPU utilization hitting a ceiling at 1%, and are unsure what the issue is

Answer (score 0):

Just one question. Why are using such small instances? How is the memory use. My guess is the same as yours. The CPU is causing the trouble.  3 micro instances are not much.
I would try to increase the instances. But it is just a guess.

Comment: Thanks @leandro-donizetti-soares  the reason why the instance type is small is because at the moment I don't have more than 10k items in the cache. The free memory shows as 430MB over 500MB that are available in total for each node. In general the stats look pretty healthy, hence my confusion

Comment: Hi. Can you send a better picture of the cpu usage? I guess it is peaking at 1.2 cores. It would not would be a problem since you have 2.